# XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. Invalid HTTP status code 400

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have WebApi Application and one MVC5 Applicatiion.I am sending request to webApi using angularJS from MVC5 Application.But it is not working fine when I send DELETE or POST request. I am getting 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. Invalid HTTP status code 400' error in Browser.But it is working fine for GET request.See the below code.

Sevice call

```
  $http.delete("http://localhost:8643/api/values/1");
```

WebApi

```
 // DELETE api/values/5

    [HttpDelete]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        var emp = employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);

        if(emp!=null)
        {
            employees.Remove(emp);
        }
    }
```

Even I have enabled Cors in my WebApi.
Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For the post try to add $.param to your object, and specify the content type.
Something like that.

```js
$http({
              method: "POST",
              url: "http://localhost:8643/api/values",
              data: $.param({'Type': 'Type', 'Name': 'Name'}),
              headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',}
            })
```

Hope this might help.
As for Delete and Put, I am still having problems with them myself.